# Benro and Manfrotto Monopods - QR System

Tags: video, dslr

I was looking into some monopods to improve my on-the-run potential for some upcoming projects and I'd like to unify all my gear with one QR system so I can switch from a slider to tripod to monopod with relative ease (if needed). I'm interested in these monopods:

1. http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/945109-REG/manfrotto_mvm500a_pro_fluid_monopod_with.html
2. http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=967703&gclid=CJ3B25_XzL8CFQYxaQodWxQA6Q&Q=&is=REG&A=details

Quality and opinions aside, I'm trying to find out the QR system used for both. What I've found is that Benro ONLY sells the QR plate and not the mounting portion, and Manfrotto has a variety of different QR systems. Can you only adapt Benro products by buying compatible Benro heads (S4 in this case), and which Manfrotto QR system is compatible with the monopod I listed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered buying an entirely separate set of QR plates to unify your entire setup? For instance, in our setup, we use a tripod, a monopod, and a GlideCam with various attachments for each of these (rail systems, teleprompters, etc.). By adding [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0010SIAV2) (relatively) cheap QR plate to the top of each stabilization method, we can switch our cameras around all systems with ease, and the QR plate can go on any standard 3/8" or 1/4" screw.

Comment: This is a good idea. I was thinking about maybe saving some money where I could by picking devices that already had the QR system I wanted to use. However, this is definitely something I'll keep in mind.

Comment: In my experience, doing this could potentially cost you more money down the road because "proprietary" QRs like that can be incredibly expensive, unlike mounting a cheaper QR (like the one linked above) onto a proprietary QR. Also, the linked QR is really nice since it has 2 level bubbles attached, one in each direction. Sometimes the levels on tripod bubbles aren't always accurate - it's best to get the level as close as possible to the camera.

Comment: Would something like this QR plate be advisable on a heavy duty shoulder rig or for usage inside of a cage or is that unrealistic?

Comment: Absolutely. We use this QR on a shoulder rig and it works beautifully. This is a high-quality and very durable product. Whenever I get a new tripod, etc. I always order another one of these QRs. I've had my oldest one for over 2 years and it's still in great shape. It's a dual-locking QR, meaning to release the top you have to both twist a "locking" part and push a button - just a little extra insurance that your camera won't come tumbling out. I've never had an issue with it.

Comment: Any idea if that plate is compatible with the Manfrotto plates?  It looks incredibly similar in design to the Manfrottos, including the tension lock and the push button latch.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the [Manfrotto 3433PL 577] (http://www.amazon.com/Manfrotto-577-Connect-Adapter-Mounting/dp/B00009XV3M/ref=cm_cd_ql_qh_dp_t) is a different size, although the two look very similar aside from the Giottos' leveling bubbles (which are a huge plus IMO).

Answer (score 0):

The [Manfrotto is a 500 series](http://www.manfrotto.com/product/8709.76909.76924.0.0/MVM500A/_/Aluminum_Fluid_Monopod_with_500_head), so it uses the [Video Camera Plate](http://www.manfrotto.us/video-camera-plate-500plong).  I'm not sure what you mean about adapting Benro products.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it. However, I wouldn't necessarily need the plate but the device that it locks into, rather. I need one plate that is screwed into my camera that would get transferred to all of my devices.

Comment: I unfortunately do not see any quick release adapter mounts for the 500PLong.